# How to return a value from another scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios

I have a function inside a function inside a function in javascript. I get my value in the inner most function, but I need to return it in the outer most one. Like this:

```
import convertPrice from "./convertPrice";
import getCountryInfoByLanguage from "./getCountryInfoByLanguage";
import axios from "axios";
export default (language, price) => {
  let countryCode, currency, formattedPrice;

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
    axios
      .get(
        `http://api.geonames.org/countryCodeJSON?lat=${
          position.coords.latitude
        }&lng=${position.coords.longitude}&username=...`
      )
      .then(response => {
        countryCode = getCountryInfoByLanguage(
          response.data.languages.split(",")[0]
        ).countryCode;
        currency = getCountryInfoByLanguage(
          response.data.languages.split(",")[0]
        ).currency;
        const convertedPrice =
          Math.round(convertPrice(price, currency) * 10) / 10;
        formattedPrice = convertedPrice.toLocaleString(countryCode, {
          style: "currency",
          currency: currency
        });
        console.log(formattedPrice);
        return formattedPrice; //This is where the value gets properly returned
      });

  });
    //this is where I want the value to be returned
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with promises, you can always returns them and call a final `then` at the end.

```
import convertPrice from "./convertPrice";
import getCountryInfoByLanguage from "./getCountryInfoByLanguage";
import axios from "axios";
export default (language, price) => {
  let countryCode, currency, formattedPrice;

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
    return axios
      .get(
        `http://api.geonames.org/countryCodeJSON?lat=${
          position.coords.latitude
        }&lng=${position.coords.longitude}&username=filipk268`
      )
      .then(response => {
        countryCode = getCountryInfoByLanguage(
          response.data.languages.split(",")[0]
        ).countryCode;
        currency = getCountryInfoByLanguage(
          response.data.languages.split(",")[0]
        ).currency;
        const convertedPrice =
          Math.round(convertPrice(price, currency) * 10) / 10;
        formattedPrice = convertedPrice.toLocaleString(countryCode, {
          style: "currency",
          currency: currency
        });
        console.log(formattedPrice);
        return formattedPrice; //This is where the value gets properly returned
      });

  }).then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
  })
};
```

Notice here that i'm returning the axios call, which returns a promise, You could even return the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` it would be accessible as a promise outside the current scope.

Comment: No, this doesn't work. I get navigator.geolocation.getcurrentposition is undefined error.

Comment: Can you  check if `navigator.geolocation` is defined ?

Comment: I checked it in my browser console and it is. The error disappears when I delete the last .then()

Comment: Try to understand what i did rather than copy paste my code.

Comment: Why should I try to understand code that's not working?

Comment: Because i'm not trying to code that for you, i'm trying to explain how promises works. If you are not happy with my answer, you can wait for somebody else to answer.